# Contour Integration - Quantum field theory

Tags: complex-analysis, mathematical-physics, contour-integration, complex-integration, quantum-field-theory

I am a physics student.
In calculating transition amplitude for Klein-Gordon real-scalar field, I encountered the integral,

$$ \frac{-i}{2(2\pi)^2\Delta x} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \,dk  \frac{ke^{ik\Delta x}}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}} $$

I can see here the integrand has branch cuts at $ k= \pm im  $
However, later they do a change of variables $ z= -ik $ and then the integral becomes,

$$ \frac{1}{2(2\pi)^2\Delta x} \int^{\infty}_{m} \,dz  \frac{ze^{-z\Delta x}}{\sqrt{z^2-m^2}} $$

And it is said that they can wrap the contour around the upper branch cut for $ \Delta x > 0 $

[image]

I am not able to see how this transformation happens and how the contour can be wrapped around the upper branch. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: pardon, but shouldn't the integration interval be from $im$ to $+i\infty$ on the $z$-integral? Also, could you provide sources for this? I too can't understand what's going on... thank you.

Comment: @YulOtani : Yes, it is similar to what you said, but then you take z to be imaginary part of a complex no. and evaluate it. You can look [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94074/contour-for-klein-gordon-field-transition-amplitude/94098?noredirect=1#94098) . Although am still wondering what exactly is happening.

Comment: There is a lot of integrals like this one in [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Methods-Quantum-Theory-Statistical-Physics/dp/0486632288/ref=la_B001HQ3L02_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1401944562&sr=1-1).